# Django social auth facebook : value of SIte URL for localhost?

Tags: facebook, django-socialauth

I have created a sample app in Django to try out social_auth. this application i'm running on localhost.

i have url **http://www.localhost.com:9000/home** which has a link to facebook login
on click of this link i'm getting tthe follwoing error
 `

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.

`

After searching online for solution, i have found that in facebook app setting **Site URL**
is making trouble.

i have set the **Site URL** **http://www.localhost.com:9000/home** , which is not correct.

what should be the correct **Site URL** value?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of URL is this - `http://www.localhost.com:9000/home`?

I think this is what you should write- `http://localhost:9000/home`. But make sure, your app is in `Sandbox` mode; since you are running your app on the local server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with sandbox mode enabled put this in Site URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^members/.*$',members),
)